# Simultaneous Quadratic Equation

Tags: linear-algebra

I faced with a simultaneous equation where the roots of the linear function gets me down with a xxxx soln

X^(1/2) + y = 11   --------(1)
Y^(1/2) + x = 7 ------------(2)
Then i start from eqn (1)
X^(1/2) =11 -y 
Squaring both sides implies X = Y^2 - 22Y +121 ---------(3)
also from eqn (2) ---- ********=11
Y^(1/2) =7 - X
SQUARE BOTH SIDES GIVES --  Y = X^2  - 14X + 49 ------- (4)

From here  i don't know how to do away the two quadratic with two variables.

Comment: LaTeX your answer!

Comment: You can substitute $3$ into $4$ (or vice versa) to eliminate one variable. Then you have a single-variable equation which will be a quartic.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for typesetting math.

Answer (score 1):

From the first equation we get
$$x^{1/2}=11-y$$ squaring we obtain
$$x=(11-y)^2$$ plugging this in the second equation
$$y^{1/2}=7-(11-y)^2$$ so $$y=(7-(11-y)^2)^2$$
Simplifying and factorizing gives
$$(y-9) \left(y^3-35 y^2+397 y-1444\right)=0$$